# GridDB transactions failing, can't open, write, or delete from specific containers

Tags: griddb

I have a simple server and am testing out adding JSON Web Tokens for an upcoming project. I was testing protected routes and made dummy GridDB Containers to test whether my simple auth middleware was working. At first, things worked and expected, but eventually my routes opening specific containers were failing -- no error code or anything else thrown on Go or from GridDB, just simple hanging of webpages.

I eventually got fed up and jumped into the CLI to drop the container but even then the the operation would hang.

I looked at my gridstore logs and found the following:

```
2023-12-05T18:13:16.915-08:00 plex 6204 ERROR TRANSACTION_SERVICE [60166:DS_CON_LOCK_CONFLICT] Transaction timed out by lock conflict (elapsedMillis=302400, timeoutMillis=300000) (reason=(pId=83, rowTxnId=1036, txnId=1664)) (User error, source={clientId=120, address=(socket closed)}, eventType=QUERY_TQL(121), partition=83, statementId=1, transaction=eca9fb9c-9813-4c81-83b9-9f3ff5b145d:1, containerId=0) <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>
2023-12-05T18:13:16.916-08:00 plex 6204 WARNING EVENT_ENGINE [130003:EE_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED] Failed to send (engine=TRANSACTION_SERVICE, eventType=121, nd={clientId=120, address=(socket closed)}, reason=Client socket already closed) <VVZvxK1BdeweF23bpkov0AsJKtCnQG2TPg9v3Lxqb9QSF2+I8lxk3R9RT8StQXX2FR5j3K0VO/YNHGTG7gMh0BQXecboYW7XHj1vwatdaMMPFniU5A9i3BUKfpKNWWTdDzxk1aFBZIlBPHzXpltT1goMb8G8YHHHEhZkmOEPbdoVHDeA8RYh0QJZX8GtXUTLGBx6xqFAb5NVVm/ErUF17B4XbdumSi/QCwkq0KdAbZM+D2/cvGpv1BIXb4jyXGTdH1FPxK1BdfYVHmPcrRU79g0cZMbuAyHQFBd5xuhhbtcePW/Bq11oww8WeJTkD2LcFQp+ko1ZZN0PPGTVoUFkiUE8fNemW1PWCgxvwbxgcccSFmSY4Q9t2hUcN4D+GiHoSko6gvgcO/Y+JkXijX1A5zI2RO2GYFXsOjVG/Z9qRe5bOmbbrUF1kwgWadmtWyHSFwtv06xWIdAXFnnXrA==>
2023-12-05T18:13:43.229-08:00 plex 6207 INFO CHECKPOINT_SERVICE [30902:CP_STATUS] [CP_END] mode=NORMAL_CHECKPOINT, backupPath=, elapsedMillis=35
```

as a quick work around, I made new containers to test but it keeps occuring to the new containers as well.

Here is my simple Go Code

```
var b strings.Builder
gridstore := ConnectGridDB()

col := GetContainer(gridstore, urlPath)

rs, err := QueryContainer(gridstore, col, "select *")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error getting container", err)
    return
}

for rs.HasNext() {
    rrow, err := rs.NextRow()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("GetNextRow err:", err)
        panic("err GetNextRow")
    }

    str := rrow[0].(string)
    fmt.Fprintln(&b, str)
}
```

These are the helper functions above, though they are very generic

```
func ConnectGridDB() griddb.Store {
    factory := griddb.StoreFactoryGetInstance()

    // Get GridStore object
    gridstore, err := factory.GetStore(map[string]interface{}{
        "notification_member": "127.0.0.1:10001",
        "cluster_name":        "myCluster",
        "username":            "admin",
        "password":            "admin"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic("err get store")
    }

    return gridstore
}

func GetContainer(gridstore griddb.Store, cont_name string) griddb.Container {
    fmt.Println("Getting container " + cont_name)
    col, err := gridstore.GetContainer(cont_name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("getting failed, err:", err)
        panic("err create query")
    }
    col.SetAutoCommit(false)

    return col
}

func QueryContainer(gridstore griddb.Store, col griddb.Container, query_string string) (griddb.RowSet, error) {
    fmt.Println("querying: ", query_string)
    query, err := col.Query(query_string)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("create query failed, err:", err)
        panic("err create query")
    }

    rs, err := query.Fetch(true)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("fetch failed, err:", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return rs, nil
}
```

Any help on this would be great!